# Android: Serializing video files

Tags: android, serialization, video

I want to send video files from the Android via network to server. How can I serialize video files in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "serialize video files" on any platform, let alone Android. Files are already "serialized" by definition.

If you want to send it to a Web service, you will need to research the API of that Web service (e.g., HTTP PUT for uploading videos) and then implement that in Android (e.g., using HttpClient).

Comment: Ok. But I want to send the video file via a socket to my own custom server application. So there needs to be a way to make the videofile "transportable" via a socket.

Comment: You want to convert a video file in a container to a transport stream, and then output it to your server.